# Hints for differentiability of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(x)= \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k}\cos(kx)}{k^{2}}$,

show that $f$ is differentiable in $]-\pi,\pi[$ using the following hint: $x = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}(-1)^{k}\frac{2}{k}\sin(kx)$ $ \forall x \in ]-\pi, \pi[$

I have used the differential quotient so far but no luck, any hints?

Furthermore, I am then asked to calculate $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^{2}}$ using the above.

Comment: Presumably you are not supposed to do this from the definition of differentiability.... I would guess you have some theorems that you are supposed to use...